# How to apply text transition to number in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3. I created a bar chart. Append text and percentage in the bar chart with animation. When bar chart draw then the number and percentage go from bottom to top to the desired location. Here is the code

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "g rect")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
    .attr("y", h)
    .on("mouseover", onMouseOver) //Add listener for the mouseover event
    ... // attach other events
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(2000)
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1)); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth() - 15)  // v4’s console.log(bands.bandwidth()) replaced v3’s console.log(bands.rangeband()).
    .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1)); })   // use .slice to remove percentage sign at the end of number
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });

    var legend = svg.append("g");

    svg.selectAll(".g.rect").append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2 - 15; })
        .attr("y", h)
        .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1) / 2);})         // use slice to remove percentage sign from the end of number
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("stroke", "papayawhip")
        .style("fill", "papayawhip");

    svg.selectAll(".g.rect").append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.percentage; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2 - 20; })
        .attr("y", h)
        .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1)) - 10; })       // use slice to remove percentage sign from the end of number
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Now I want to apply text transition. Like instead of just printing say 90%(d.percentage). I want that it starts from 0 and goes to d.percentage gradually. How can I apply text transition in this case. I tried the following but it didn't work

```
svg.selectAll(".g.rect").append("text")
.text(function(d) { return d.percentage; })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2 - 20; })
.attr("y", h)
.transition()
.ease(d3.easeLinear)
.duration(2000)
.tween("text", function(d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.percentage.slice(0, -1));
        return function(t) {
            d3.select(this).text(i(t));
        };
})
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1)) - 10; })       // use slice to remove percentage sign from the end of number
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Comment: your tween function returns a d3 selection. it should just `return i;`. Also look if it should not be `attrTween('text', ....)`

Comment: I tried to return I but it is not working. I tried this `.tween("text", function(d) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.percentage.slice(0, -1));
            return i;
    })`. But still not working ...

Comment: and if you do `.attrTween("text", function(d) { var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.percentage.slice(0, -1)); return i; })`

Comment: `.attrTween('text')` is also not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you `return function(t) { ... }` and try to access `this` of parent function inside. The solution is to return arrow function, which does not shadow `this` value:

```
return t => d3.select(this).text(i(t));
```

(by the way, you may also want to round percentage before printing)

-------------Edit --------------

Here is the working code

```
var numberFormat = d3.format("d");

svg.selectAll(".g.rect").append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2 - 20; })
.attr("y", h)
.transition()
.ease(d3.easeLinear)
.duration(2000)
.tween("text", function(d) {
        var element = d3.select(this);
        var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.percentage.slice(0, -1));
        return function(t) {
            var percent = numberFormat(i(t));
            element.text(percent + "%");
        };
        //return t => element.text(format(i(t)));
})
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.percentage.slice(0, -1)) - 10; })       // use slice to remove percentage sign from the end of number
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: yes you are right. It is working. But on older browsers arrow function is not recognized. On IE 9. But you are right. Arrow function is working on Edge or Chrome. But not on IE 9

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `this` value.

Save it in the closure (`that`).

Use a number interpolator so you can round the result to a number of decimals.

```js
var ptag = d3.select('body').append('p');

ptag.transition()
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .duration(2000)
  .tween("text", function(d) {
    var that = this;
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 90);  // Number(d.percentage.slice(0, -1))
    return function(t) {
        d3.select(that).text(i(t).toFixed(2));
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Basit: if I press "Run Code Snippet" it works (in Chrome).

Comment: Ah Sorry. Yes you are right it is working. I used `this` but didn't use `d3.select(that)`. Yes you are right. I am very sorry. It is working. Please forgive me. Actually I accepted the `Yaroslav Sergienko` answer because I tried it before your provided answer. And it answer worked. Then I modified it for closure and it worked on my code too and then your answer came. But please I am again sorry for my wrong comment. I can see if I can remove it. Thanks for your help friend :)